# How to disable Jenkins automatically cleanup workspace?

Tags: jenkins

I noticed that Jenkins cleaned up some of jobs' workspace.

Is it a feature? If yes, how can I disable it?

Comment: Can you provide more information - normal behaviour is to keep the workspace. Is it deleted before or after the job starts? You can configure the log retention, but this relates only to the logs and reportings. Another point is the VCS Check-out strategy to check. Did you installed a plugin that provides such behaviour?

Comment: I'm using the default svn plugin. After some hours(I don't know how many), the build history were deleted and the workspace was cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , Workspace cleanup process will start for many reasons.

- SVN lock or conflict.
- Wrong path.

Check whether define SVN locations is exist. If one of location not available the Jenkins job will try to checkout fresh workspace again and again.

-Etc

Comment: Yes, I remember I redefined the svn checkout url. Thank you.